# Datastax Enterprise + Solr: Unable to query table: Unavailable shards for ranges

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

We recently moved an existing Cassandra cluster to DSE and are trying to create a new keyspace with solr search enabled.

We have followed the DataStax Enterprise getting started guide @ http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchTutCreatTab.html

Our `nodetool status` is as follows

````
Datacenter: nephos-1
====================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.129.196.6   578.42 GB  256     21.4%  043a2f6b-af67-433b-82c9-545521840183  r1
UN  10.129.196.21  657.12 GB  256     18.4%  91ef191a-90b3-448e-93fc-b96bc20134b3  r1
UN  10.129.196.4   572.69 GB  256     18.5%  706a78a4-02a0-45b5-91ec-78a1466a5b83  r1
UN  10.129.196.20  633.65 GB  256     23.0%  b13c9af9-510b-4c84-994d-e7dd76d70335  r1
UN  10.129.196.5   472.11 GB  256     18.6%  ca217361-0390-4eb2-ac09-5303d5f639d0  r1   
```
````

Our keyspace config is as follows:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE nhanes_ks3 WITH replication = {
  'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
  'nephos-1': '3'
};
```

The specific error we get is as follows:

```
java.io.IOException: Unavailable shards for ranges: [(-7387413954048418055,-7385338481486867046], (-7968649137587749694,-7963978319820795254], (1313382724605553296,1319385075089218248], (-518923653484422343,-505515211219774468], (4878421572270955033,4914518257072996455], (-844700479033064369,-776944140537025276], (-69308347594152481,-68921876667069098], (4871809831310454903,4876975265107356578], (3271109328123695599,3274195026207869261], (-8483313673665218401,-8454834139936236432], (-3395613676758459575,-3372444966011531863],
```

All our nodes are `Saerch - Active` according to OpsCenter and up.

Comment: Killachaos are you still seeing this? If so could you provide the output from dsetool ring?

Comment: Sorry htran, I didn't follow this as we decided to pursue another solutoin. Here is our current dse ring - https://gist.github.com/nemothekid/9b55c93bd66b63792ede

Comment: The workload being "unknown" from dsetool is very troubling.  At what point did you get the unavailable shard for ranges error? On core creation? On query? My suspicion is that because dsetool can't figure out that the node is a search node, that the ShardRouter used to determine which nodes to query for data isn't working properly either.

Comment: The error was on query when we tried to set it up. The nodes currently are all "normal cassandra nodes" (not search) however.